# Network configuration problem with 2 network cards

Tags: debian, networking

I have a Debian "jessie" machine configured to work with two different Wi-Fi USB dongles. The first one (`wlan0`) creates an ad-hoc wireless network using `hostapd`, while the second one (`wlan1`) *should* try to connect to my home network using `wpa_supplicant`. Here's the relevant part of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# Ad-hoc wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.16.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Infrastructure wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

While `hostapd` serves the ad-hoc network, clients are given an IP address using `dnsmasq`.

Now, *sometimes* everything work fine: I boot the system, my ad-hoc network is broadcasted, DHCP by `dnsmasq` works fine, and the second interface connects to my home Wi-Fi and gets an IP address.

However *some other times*, it happens that while the ad-hoc network is initialized and works perfectly, the second interface does not connect to my home network and, instead, it gets an IP address from the first one. When this happens, here's the output of `ifconfig`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.16.42.1  Bcast:172.16.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.16.42.18  Bcast:172.16.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

Note that `wlan1`'s `inet addr` should be the one provided by my home router, and not that one.

I thought that maybe this problem has to do with boot order: `dnsmasq` may be started too early or too late, but I'm not sure. What do you think? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You would better specify the SSID of your home network in wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro of course I did that. wpa_supplicant is correctly configured; indeed, sometimes it connects to my network successfully during boot, or it connects to it after I restart the networking.

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition where your `wlan1` will take the first IP address it gets back regardless of whether it comes from dnsmasq (wrong) or your home router (right).  Add the following lines to your dnsmasq config to make it not respond to requests coming from `wlan1`

```
dhcp-mac=blacklist,<wlan1 MAC address>
dhcp-ignore=blacklist
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Indeed dnsmasq was already configured to only accept requests coming from wlan0, and blacklisting wlan1 didn't solve the problem. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Two thoughts:  1) It might be worth while to change the subnet on wlan0 just so it's not the same as the default auto-conf subnet. 2) your dnsmasq configs aren't working because wlan1 *is* getting an IP from dnsmasq (unless it's doing an auto-conf and just landing in the same subnet...see thought #1).

Comment: I guess the other possibility is that wlan1 might be connecting to the SSID broadcast by wlan0.  Can you confirm that wlan1 always connects to the correct SSID?

Comment: I changed the subnet mask on wlan0, as you suggested, and now everything seems to work fine. I didn't fully understand *how* and *why*... but at least it works. Also, wlan1 wasn't connecting to the SSID broadcast by wlan0. Thank you by the way.